# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

On this question, [Does HR asking for salary slips and earliest joining date mean I have got the job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/41129/3192), I had a rather late realization that the OP is likely to be from India. I hadn't noticed his name card at first, and by then I already had an edit to the question approved.

I thought it would be appropriate to include [india](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) on the question, but I didn't want to appear to be a rep-whore, so I requested the OP to add that tag himself. I made another comment there where I was responding to another user. I see both my comments have been deleted.

I can totally understand why the second comment was deleted, and I agree completely. However, the first comment was clearly an attempt to improve the question (and I explained why I didn't want to do it myself), so I cannot quite figure out why that had to be deleted too.

Interestingly enough, there are still some other comments there which are responding to the question, which have not been deleted. Could one of the moderators please explain to me what is the policy on comments, and why it seems to be applied somewhat inconsistently?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thank you for asking the OP for clarification.  You used comments exactly the way we want people to: to request clarification.

When I saw the comment the question had been edited to add the [india](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) tag, so your comment (and the OP's response with the information) were obsolete and I removed them.  That wasn't a judgement about the comments; they'd done their job and weren't needed any more.

On the second, I'd meant to delete both the one you replied to and yours, to fend off a discussion in the comments about whether the question belongs.  Better ways to register such feelings are close votes, meta, and chat.  I goofed, and have now remedied that.  Thanks for catching this.

Answer (score 8):

Also, moderating comments is often very time consuming. We often get long trains of comments which are either inflammatory, obsolete, or off-topic and sorting out which to keep/delete gets complicated.

Sometimes, good comments will get deleted in the crossfire... this is unfortunate but a problem of human moderators without unlimited time :)

Comment: I totally understand that, but I found it rather strange that out of the 6 or so comments there, only the 2 that I made were deleted and other comments like "Why dont you ask them?" "What do you think it means?" were left alone. This is also not the first time I have seen this happen. The previous times, I ignored it as a glitch or human error, but I had reason to believe I was being targeted for being outside the "group", so just wanted to clarify that was not the case.

Comment: @Happy you were not being targeted.  I'm sorry I gave you that impression.  (I did also delete a response from the OP that had since been edited into the question, BTW.)