# Did my comment get deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

In addition to a well received answer on [this thread](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/142408/how-to-think-about-joining-a-company-whose-business-i-do-not-understand/142410#142410), I originally made a comment underneath the question suggesting to the OP that he should avoid stating his *bad financial situation* ("broke" - his own words) to a potential employer involved  in the *finance* sector.

I've had friends who were denied employment or were outright fired when it was discovered they had bad credit.  One of which was a well known bank.  I honestly didn't want the OP to walk into an interview with a company that deals in money and tip that he's desperate for money.  Probably good advice for any interview.

I happened to notice the comment has since disappeared.  Did it get deleted for a particular reason?  I could easily amend my formal answer to include it, but I'm curious if it was deleted because someone thought it wasn't serious or came across as too snarky.

Comment: It's probably worth looking at [this thread](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not?rq=1).

Comment: @JaneS and [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3053/73791) one... and [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4492/73791) other... aaaand [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2987/73791) other... I think we need a Canonical Post regarding comments being deleted so we have a good post to use as dupe target of these sort of questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was my comment deleted?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/why-was-my-comment-deleted)

Answer (score 5):

Your comment wasn't viewed as being snarky.  As you indicated, it was an attempt (in part) to answer the question.

From the linked [What "comments" are not . . .](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not?noredirect=1&lq=1) meta question:

> **Comments are not for answers**
>   Comments are not a substitute for answering questions. Comments cannot easily be searched, nor can they be edited for corrections or vetted with the community vote. There's no history, no reputation awarded, nor can they be 'accepted' as the best answer. They get little visibility but often keep users from posting proper answers because the question appears to be resolved… albeit, incorrectly. Further, those comment-answers will not bring new users to this site searching for the information. In short, you are hurting rather than helping the site, and your contribution is at great risk of being lost/deleted.

Additionally, answers in comments are often short and lack enough detail to be truly useful.

Some users answer in comments because they don't have the time or inclination to offer a fuller answer but still want their opinion to be heard (and possibly expanded on by others).

Comment: So, deleting comments that are probably "helpful" to the OP is the standard response then.